# Regex for matching expression that consists of single digit numbers and operators

Tags: python, regex

I would like to create a regex that will validate that a string is an equation made up of a **single** digits and either the `*` or `+` operator and is no longer than 100 characters.  So these would be valid:

```
1+2*3*8+0
9
9*9
```

And these would **not** be valid:

```
1++1
12+1
2*25
1+
47
+
+1
11
```

I came up with the regex below to accomplish this:

```
^(\d{1}[\+\*]{1}){0,99}\d$
```

Which *appears* to work, but I'm curious if there is a cleaner way to accomplish this.  Any suggestions or is this about as clean as it gets?

It is saved [here](http://regexr.com/3cune) if you would like to play with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- While your regex appears to work, it will fail for the condition that your expression should not exceed 100 characters mark. With the boundary of `{0,99}` on a 2 character pattern `\d{1}[\*\+]{1}`, you are already expecting a possible expression of length 198 characters.
- Using `{1}` quantifier is just redundant.
- No need for escaping inside a character set. The only things needing a leading backslash (`\`) inside a characters list are `]` and `^`, where the caret is the only character inside, or the first.
- Your expressions will not reach a 100 character mark, unless you allow the `+` to act as an unary operator.

Therefore, the following pattern will be the simplest approach (imo)

```
^(?:\d[*+]){0,49}\d$
```

which is the tiniest bit modified from your original expression.

You can check the pattern in [action here](https://www.regex101.com/r/nK1uF1/1) on the following expressions:

```
1+2*3*8+0
9
9*9
1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+5*8

1++1
12+1
2*25
1+
47
+
+1
11
1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+1*2+5*8+9
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Explicit length check for clarity

You checked the length of the string inside the regular expression, it was not obvious and @hjpotter92 found a bug in it. His fix uses half of the desired length inside the regexp making it even less intuitive.

I suggest using as a regexp `^(?:\d[*+])*\d$` and checking the length separately.